# Change song number font color with songs.sty

Tags: songs

I'm using `songs.sty` to create a songbook.

I figured out how to change the background color of the song number boxes by redefining `\snumbgcolor` like `\renewcommand{\snumbgcolor}{green}`.

[image: Song title]

I can also change the background color in the index with `\renewcommand{\idxbgcolor}{green}`.

Is there an easy way to change the font color for these to white?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[lyric]{songs}
\renewcommand{\snumbgcolor}{green}

\begin{document}

\begin{songs}{}

\beginsong{Bella Notte}[sr={\footnotesize Mel: Bella Notte}, cr={}]

\beginchorus
Nu er det nat, en vidunderlig nat,
åh så stille Bella Notte
\endchorus
\beginverse
Stjernernes skær, bringer himlen så nær,
jeg vil drømme Bella Notte
\endverse

\endsong

\end{songs}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: I have added a MWE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it's not exactly the standard solution, but by listing all commands from the `songs` package and keeping only stuff with “num” in it using `latexdef -ll -p songs | grep num`, I found the command `\printsongnum`. Here is a redefinition of it, only adding the white color:

```
\renewcommand{\printsongnum}[1]{%
    \sffamily \bfseries \LARGE \color{white}#1%
}
```

It seems to work if I put it in the preamble of your example. Since there aren't a hundred `@` signs in the command, let's assume it's not a dirty trick xD

Comment: Nice sleuth work!

Answer (score 1):

I confirm it works, and give an illustration. B.t.W;, needless to use  the `usenames` option, as it's the default now.

```
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% !Mode:: "TeX:Hard:UTF-8"
% PDFLaTeX this document and view or print it from Acrobat Reader!
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Preamble Starts here:
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lyric]{songs}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\renewcommand{\snumbgcolor}{SeaGreen!60}
\renewcommand{\printsongnum}[1]{\color{white}\bfseries\Huge#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{songs}{}

\beginsong{How doth the little crocodile}[by={Lewis Carroll}]

\beginverse
How doth the little crocodile\\
   Improve his shining tail,\\
 And pour the waters of the Nile\\
   On every golden scale! \bigskip

 How cheerfully he seems to grin,\\
   How neatly spreads his claws,\\
 And welcomes little fishes in\\
   With gently smiling jaws!
   \endverse

\endsong

\end{songs}

\end{document}
```

[image]